# Opencv 3.2 read mpeg files too slow

Tags: c++, opencv3.2

I am going through the book Learning OpenCV 3 and test out the video example 2.3. I could edit, compile and run it, but the problem is that it closed down immediately.

```
// DisplayPicture.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" // Include file for every supported OpenCV function 


#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    namedWindow("video3", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open( string(argv[1]));
    int tell = 0;
    Mat frame;
    for (;;) {
        cap >> frame;
        //waitKey(30);
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            break;
            //end of film
        }
        imshow("video3", frame);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found that my computer processed the data too fast. It could not read the next frame fast enough. `if (frame.empty())` became true the program reached the `break` statement and ended.

By adding a `waitkey` of 30 millisec before viewing the image frame, the video program works very well. At least I can view the video. Since this example is from the 'bible' it should work, but not with my computer.

I am running a **MSI gt72 2PE** computer with **nvidia gtx880m**. Not sure if that matters.

I assume that adding a `waitKey(30)` is not appropriate, so I am seeking suggestions as to what could be done differently.